# Get the list of latest tweets using node.js and twitterAPI

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I got a problem to get the tweets from my account from the twitter API 1.1. Since I am new to node.js. I used twitter module and my intialization looks like this

```
twitter = require('twitter');
var twit = new twitter(params);
twit.get('http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?count=2',{include_entities:false},);
```

But when I log the data I get this

```
[Error: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized]statusCode: 401, data: '{"errors":[{"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}]}' }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an API key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error message is very clear, you need to authenticate app

```
var util = require('util'),
    twitter = require('twitter');
var twit = new twitter({
    consumer_key: 'STATE YOUR NAME',
    consumer_secret: 'STATE YOUR NAME',
    access_token_key: 'STATE YOUR NAME',
    access_token_secret: 'STATE YOUR NAME'
});
```

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline

https://npmjs.org/package/twitter

Comment: Also it is strange because if I just use http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json the nit returns some results but if I add any other params then the error appears.

Comment: @bpawan you are not supposed to share your keys. Immediately remove those.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found that any query parameters is supposed to be added in the second parameter on the twit.get() function.

So in your case it should be:

```
twit.get('/statuses/user_timeline.json', { count: 1 }, func);
```